# Android : Retain Focus on current edit text on Screen lock / unlock

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-softkeyboard, lockscreen

I've a screen with few `edit texts`.
While entering data on one of those fields, I simply press lock screen button
When I unlock the phone, keyboard remains open and focus is lost.
I know `onPause()/ onResume() lifecycle methods` will be called.

But I want to know best approach for this since I need to implement this throughout my app.